# Parsing JSON returned via an AJAX POST formating issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a php returning some json in response to a POST request made via an ajax function.
In my php function I format the data like this:

```
//json return
$return["answers"] = json_encode($result);
echo json_encode($return);
```

This returns the following string:

```
answers: "[{"aa":"Purple","0":"Purple","ab":"Blue","1":"Blue","ac":"Red","2":"Red","ad":"Yellow","3":"Yellow"}]"
```

And this is where I am trying to catch it to use the data:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://ldsmatch.com/pieces/functions/question.functions.php",
            dataType : 'JSON',
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data.answers[0]["aa"]);
            }       
        });
```

I've been trying to just alert the data so I can visualize it before setting up the vars I need, but am having some trouble formatting it correctly so it is usable.

If I alert `data.answers[0]` then it just shows me the first character in the string, which is a bracket [ and if i subsequently change the number it will go through each character in the returned string.

I have tried other variations, such as:

```
data.answers[0]["aa"]   (this returns 'undefined' in the alert)
data.answers["aa"]      (this returns 'undefined' in the alert)
data.answers[0]         (this returns the first character of the string)
```

I feel like I'm close, but missing something.  Any guidance appreciated.

edit:

thanks for all the suggestions. I removed the second json_encode and was able to parse with `data.answers[0].aa`

Comment: @palaѕн just did and it returned undefined. also tried data.answers.aa[0] which returned `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`  cheers.

Comment: what are you getting for `console.log(data)`? Please post it here...

Comment: u can use alert(JSON.stringify(data));

Comment: just put this line in success function console.log(data); and check firebug it will help you more.

Comment: @SohilDesai that seems to just log the string, which I already know exists and is formatted: `Object {answers: "[{"aa":"Purple","0":"Purple","ab":"Blue","1":"Blue…"ac":"Red","2":"Red","ad":"Yellow","3":"Yellow"}]"}
`

Comment: @palaѕн it returns
`Object {answers: "[{"aa":"Purple","0":"Purple","ab":"Blue","1":"Blue…"ac":"Red","2":"Red","ad":"Yellow","3":"Yellow"}]"}
`

Comment: first change php code like this $return["answers"] = $result;
echo json_encode($return);  and then check response in console. otherwise according to your data, you are doing correct..

Comment: @SohilDesai removing that second json_encode helped. Then I was able to get the first string using `data.answers[0].aa`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

success: function(data) {
                var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                alert(json.answers[0]["aa"]);
            }

Comment: this essentially worked, but I also removed the second json_encode and was able to get the result using data.answers[0].aa without doing a parse in the js.

Answer (score 0):

Use parseJson like this

```
var json = $.parseJSON(data);
$(json).each(function(i,val){
    $.each(val,function(k,v){
      console.log(k+" : "+ v);     
    });
});
```

Comment: Console returns: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o jquery.js:550
x.extend.parseJSON jquery.js:550
$.ajax.success subpage.questions.js:105
c jquery.js:3074
p.fireWith jquery.js:3186
k jquery.js:8253
r`

Answer (score 0):

What if you remove double-encoding on PHP side? You've got an object with JSON string instead of object with first property being object itself, or you may explicitly decode "answers" property on client side as it was suggested above.